# SQL Server login failures

Tags: sql-server

I have created a SQL Server database via Visual Studio 2017 as a Microsoft Azure SQL database project. The project includes the creation of a user/login:

```
CREATE LOGIN [MyDbOwner] WITH PASSWORD = '{password}'

CREATE USER [MyDbOwner]
    FROM LOGIN MyDbOwner
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo    
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'MyDbOwner';
GO

GRANT CONNECT TO [MyDbOwner]
```

I have deployed the project locally (`localhost\SQLEXPRESS`) and to Azure, finding similar problems in both environments. I can confirm in the local database that the 'MyDbOwner' user has been created and has `db_owner` role membership.

For the local deployment, I am using a connection string thus:

```
Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database={my-database};User ID=MyDbOwner;Password={password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=30;
```

I am getting the following error message:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Login failed for user 'MyDbOwner'

I have successfully used this technique before, on other databases. At present, my work-around locally is to use Windows Authentication, and on Azure to use a 'user@domain' account created through the portal.

Why can't I use `CREATE LOGIN` users now, where it has worked (and continues to work) on other databases, both locally and in Azure?

**Edit:**

Found an entry in the Windows Application event log stating

> Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided

I can confirm that the password used in the `CREATE LOGIN` is only upper/lower case letters and digits, and the password provided in the connection string is exactly the same.

**Edit:**

I had assumed that I could publish my database with CREATE LOGIN commands, edit the password(s) and re-publish, and SQL Server would update the login(s) with the new passwords (a flow which had in fact occurred leading to the onset of my problem).

Comment: Do you see anything in the SQL Server logs for the denied login attempt?

Comment: @Larnu I will amend my question... just checked Windows Application event log, found login failure event with reason "Password did not match that for the login provided", but I can confirm that the password in the connection string exactly matches the password used in the CREATE LOGIN, no special characters, only upper/lower case letters and digits.

Comment: I hate to say it, but if the error is they don't match, then, for whatever reason, they don't.

Comment: @Larnu Point taken, but I have re-created the database from script, and debugged the code which handles the connection string in order to confirm that the passwords do, in fact, match.

Comment: The Login won't be mapped to the database, so recreating the database won't change that. Might be worth issuing a statement to ensure that the password is correct on the SQL Server: `ALTER LOGIN [MyDbOwner] WITH PASSWORD = '{Password}';` *Obviously change `{Password}` to the correct password for the Login.*

Comment: @Larnu Found that ALTER LOGIN worked to get passwords in sync. My problem seems to stem from relying on project deployment to properly set or update passwords to that of the script. Bear in mind that I have deleted the database, edited the CREATE LOGIN, re-deployed, and found that the password set by the newly executed CREATE LOGIN doesn't work.

Comment: No, a new `CREATE LOGIN` won't work, as the Login already existed. Login's are server level. If you `CREATE` a login, and then try to `CREATE` it again, the statement will simply fail. Users are database level, Logins are Server level. This is why you were receiving the error *"Password did not match that for the login provided"*; because the password was (unsurprisingly) wrong. You had set a different password previously and there you were under the belief that dropping the database would delete the Login. This is not the case; hence a `ALTER LOGIN` statement was required. :)

Comment: @Larnu I think this brings my problem into focus. I have CREATE LOGINs in my database project; when I re-publish, I don't see errors due to creating an existing login, leading me to (falsely) believe the CREATE is effectively ALTERing the LOGIN (or dropping/re-creating) when it is in fact quietly ignoring it.